# Linux LVM replicated Volumes

Tags: linux, storage, migration, lvm, replication

I am migrating storage arrays, on two sites.The DR site has synchronous block replication from main site that will be cut during the migration, however once the volumes are migrated the replication will be restarted.

The servers to which the storage is attached are running RHEL 6. My question is, since this is a block replication will I need to do any reconfig on the DR machine at LVM level? I mean since the source disk will be a new one and its ID will change, will these affect the volumes on destination? Will a pvscan,vgscan be enough?

Thank you,

Comment: If you're using names or UUIDs, and you aren't changing them, then you ought to be fine.

Comment: how will you copy data from  OldA,OldB to NewA, NewB ?

Comment: Do you mean the LVM migration? If so, by using LVM mirroring something like: http://www.tecmint.com/lvm-storage-migration/, Is that wha you mean?